# How can I reduce the Lambda Cold Start time in my code?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jdbc, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am developing a REST API for a mobile app. The mobile app is expected to have millions of users, and used on daily basis.

I am using the `AWS Lambda`, `API Gateway`, `Amazon RDS (MySQL)` technologies for this. In addition, I am using the `CloudFormation` file to configure everything.

I noticed that each function here has a cold start time of **3 seconds to 3.8 seconds**. This needs to be reduced as much as possible.

**HikariCPDataSource**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

public class HikariCPDataSource {
    
    private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    private static HikariDataSource ds;
    
    static {
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://gfgf.ffgfg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/aaaa");
        config.setUsername("admin");
        config.setPassword("admin123");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
    
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return ds.getConnection();
    }
    
    private HikariCPDataSource(){}
}
```

**GetAllAccountTypesLambda**

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.peresiaapp.beans.AccountingType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.*;
public class GetAllAccountTypesLambda {
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   static final String QUERY = "SELECT * from accounting_type";
   static Connection conn = null;
   static {
      try {
         conn = HikariCPDataSource.getConnection();
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent getAllAccountTypes(APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent request)
         throws JsonProcessingException, ClassNotFoundException {
      List<AccountingType> list = new ArrayList<>();
      AccountingType acc = new AccountingType();
      try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(QUERY);) {
         // Extract data from result set
         while (rs.next()) {
            // Retrieve by column name
            acc.setIdaccountingType(rs.getInt("idaccounting_Type"));
            acc.setType(rs.getString("type"));
            list.add(acc);
         }
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      String writeValueAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(list);
      return new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent().withStatusCode(200).withBody(writeValueAsString);
   }
}
```

**template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aaaa-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aaaa-restapi

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 100

Resources:
  GetAllAccountTypesLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aaaa-restapi
      Handler: com.peresiaapp.dao.accountingtype.GetAllAccountTypesLambda::getAllAccountTypes
      Runtime: java11
      MemorySize: 1024
      Environment: # More info about Env Vars: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#environment-object
        Variables:
          PARAM1: VALUE
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /accounttype
            Method: get
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f2459dcd921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-0381dfdfd
          - subnet-c4ddf54cb
  
  GetAllRolesLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aaaa-restapi
      Handler: com.peresiaapp.dao.accountingtype.GetAllRolesLambda::getAllRoles
      Runtime: java11
      MemorySize: 1024
      Environment: # More info about Env Vars: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#environment-object
        Variables:
          PARAM1: VALUE
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /roles
            Method: get
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f2459dcd921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-0381sds2d
          - subnet-c4d5sdsb
  
  LambdaRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DescribeInstances
                  - ec2:AttachNetworkInterface
                Resource: '*'
```

**********UPDATE*********

Couple of comments suggests me of provisioned concurrency. I did try. Did not see much of a difference. However, if any of you can explain what is below that is **900 available** is, that would be great. I have hundreds of functions, does this also mean I have to spend a HUGE amount of money if I turned on concurrency? Because figures in `pricing` page seems to be different and that is okay with me - https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/

[image]

Comment: Does it even make sense to use Hikari in a lambda as that instance should be used only once? Not sure how much that adds to the startup time though. This might also be useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/lambda-optimize-starttime.html

Comment: @Thomas: I have no idea Thomas. There are mixed comments about using a connection pool with Lambda, some say yes, some say no. I used this for testing. Hikeri is because it is the fastest.

Comment: @Thomas: I have posted my cloud formation file, please take a look?

Comment: @JustCause Java is one of the slowest options for AWS Lambda when it comes to cold boot. The JVM does need some time to start. Other options like Javascript, Go or Dotnet have much, much faster cold start times. If you have to stick to Java you might be able to solve this issue by [using the RDS proxy that Lambda provides](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/). There is also the option of provisioned concurrency or [native images](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/graalvm-native-image-support-in-the-aws-sdk-for-java-2-x/).

Comment: Have you tried using provisioned concurrency? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-provisioned-concurrency-for-lambda-functions/

Comment: Hmm, maybe you want to test with and without Hikari to see the differences. I also assume that establishing the connection to the DB is taking some time so you might want to reuse your lambda and maybe keep some instances around for faster response times.
Have a look at [Provisioned Concurrency]( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html#configuration-concurrency-provisioned) for this - using a local connection pool might still not make sense in this case since there'd be no concurrency within the lambda itself.

Comment: Also have a look here which seems to be a nice analysis on what impacts cold start times: https://blog.symphonia.io/posts/2020-06-30_analyzing_cold_start_latency_of_aws_lambda

Comment: @Thomas: Provisioned concurrency, yes I tried. I do not know how the pricing structure works, can you please check my updated question for more info?

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha: Provisioned concurrency, yes I tried. I do not know how the pricing structure works, can you please check my updated question for more info?

Comment: @Jens: Thank you for the advice Jens. Can you explain how this is going to help me please? Looking at it, it looks like it will be benefitted only of I have a big load on server?

Answer (score 0):

- [Enable tiered compilation to stop at level 1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/optimizing-aws-lambda-function-performance-for-java/)
- Test various memory settings to find the most optimal. CPU increases with memory allocated and you are most likely constrained on CPU - [AWS Lambda Power Tuning](https://github.com/alexcasalboni/aws-lambda-power-tuning)